# How sonos IOS app works streaming in background?

Tags: ios, streaming, sonos

**How sonos IOS app works streaming in background?**
**They are using Airplay or another technique?**

Answer (score 1):

Sonos is not sending the audio from the device to the speaker - the speaker makes the request directly. This passes the "beer run test" which allows you to leave with you phone with interrupting the music that others are listening to.

Comment: I did not get your comment . How sonos make request? Can you explain in detail Please.  Thanks @allison for comment